# Number of reflexive, symmetric, and anti-symmetric relations on a set with 3 elements

Tags: combinatorics

For the set $X=\{1,2,3\}$, I know that

$2^{{n+1}\choose 2}$ is the number of symmetric relations on $X$,

and I also know that $2^{n^2 - n}$ is the number of reflexive relations on $X$.

How can I calculate the number of reflexive, symmetric and anti-symmetric relations on X?

Comment: Would symmetry and anti-symmetry not require that the only relations are $1R1$, $2R2$, and $3R3$?. Then you take all subsets of that?

Comment: This is a duplicate...

Comment: @user178543 so you mean the power set of $\{(1,1), (2,2), (3,3)\}$?

Comment: @MattS could you please share the link to the duplicate? I cannot find it.

Comment: @Javiator I can't find the exact question either. Maybe it just looked familiar. Sorry.

Comment: @Javiator, yes. Suppose $iRj$ where $i\neq j$. Then symmetry requires $jRi$. But then anti-symmetry requires $i=j$.

Comment: Come to think of it, reflexivity will require that every element is related to itself. So I think the answer is just 1 relation satisfies your criteria.

Comment: Yes, I think so too. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to find the number of relations on $X$ that are reflexive, symmetric and anti-symmetric.  Since the relation is reflexive, it contains the diagonal elements $\{(x,x): x \in X\}$.  Since the relation is symmetric, if it contains an off-diagonal element $(x,y)$, where $x \ne y$, then it must also contain its transpose $(y,x)$.  But since the relation is also antisymmetric, if it contains an off-diagonal element $(x,y)$, then it must NOT contain its transpose $(y,x)$.  The only way both these conditions can be satisfied is that the relation not contain any off-diagonal elements at all in the first place.  Hence the relation is exactly the set of diagonal elements.  Thus there is only one relation on $X$ that is reflexive, symmetric and anti-symmetric.

Comment: Perfect explanation!